# How to determine the maximum number of supported multisample samples

Tags: opengl, sdl, antialiasing, sdl-2

I'm using SDL 2 for an OpenGL based application and I'm currently implementing anti-aliasing with code like this:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, samples);
```

But I don't want to hardcode the antialising level so I want to let the user choose the value from a list of valid values. The problem is I have no idea how to find out which values are supported on the users machine. On my gaming machine I can choose a maximum value of 16 but on my laptop I can only choose 4. Any higher setting triggers the error message `Couldn't find matching GLX visual`.

So how can I find out what maximum value I can use for the `SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES` attribute?

Answer (score 3):

As multisampling is a pixel format attribute I don't think there is a way to query it from OpenGL. You will probably need to do this on an operating specific level although I am not sure how you would fit that in with using SDL.

Answer (score 3):

This is a 4 years old question, but in case people lands here:
There is a way to get this piece of information. You have to use `glGetIntegerv ( GL_MAX_SAMPLES, &maxSamples );` but unfortunately, you can only do this once your window has been created. So you have to create a temporary window without multisampling, get all required information from openGL, then close this window and create the real one.

If you want to hide this temporary window creation to the user, you can create it using the `SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN` flag. A "loading screen" can also do the trick:

- Open a "loading application data..." screen that does not require antialiasing.
- Use it to call `glGetIntegerv` and other things like that.
- Load your application data, textures...
- Close this window and open the final one with antialiasing. :)

Comment: Another good option is to create the default framebuffer without multisampling, then query for the maximum sample count and use that information to create an FBO with multisampled renderbuffers that you render into, then call `glBlitFramebuffer` to resolve samples and copy into the default framebuffer for display. This might or might not be slightly slower than rendering into a multisampled default framebuffer, depending on how it's implemented behind the scenes, but has the added benefit that you can change sample counts on the fly at runtime, for example to implement a graphics options menu.

Comment: I do not see  GL_MAX_SAMPLES listed in https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGet.xhtml, only in ES reference (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glGet.xhtml). Is is really supported by desktop OpenGL?

Comment: this is not reliable. I get 32 max samples, and when trying to create a window with that sample count, I get an error.

Answer (score 2):

just ask (wglChoosePixelFormatARB | glXChooseVisual )!
if they don`t support you desired sample count, they dont return a pixelformat.

```
        const int piAttribIList[] =
    {
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB, WGL_FULL_ACCELERATION_ARB,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
        WGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS_ARB, 1,
        WGL_SAMPLES_EXT, 4,
        0 // zero term
    };
    const float pfAttribFList[] = { 0.0f };

    int piFormats;
    unsigned int nNumFormats;
    assert(wglChoosePixelFormatARB(m_Ptr->m_hDC, piAttribIList, pfAttribFList, 1, &piFormats, &nNumFormats));
```

if nNumFormats is > 0 then WGL_SAMPLES_EXT, 4, is supported

if nNUmFOrmats is 0  WGL_SAMPLES_EXT == 4 is not supported

there is no need to create fake contexts

on my opengl, latest nvidia drvier.
glGetIntegerv ( GL_MAX_SAMPLES, &maxSamples );  gives me 32
but i cant create a context with 32 mutlisample maybe 32 is true for offscreenframebuffers.